# How to share in this format?

Tags: android

[image]

How to share icon,text,url of the app as shown in the above image? Icon should be sent from drawable, I have tried all the `shareintents.putExtras()` and etc.. nothing is working for me.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Before posting, read [How to post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have to add more details, like what you tried so far, what failed and with what error it failed. Also consider specifying exactly what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **This isn't your job, it's the shared-to app's job.**

**Explanation:** Facebook created a protocol called [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/), which apps like Facebook and Whatsapp use to get info about the what image to be displayed and what text to show.

To be able to have something like your included picture, you'd have to first own the website you are sharing links to, then you'd have to include this meta data in your html:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Text to be displayed." />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Possibly a deep link to your app." />
<meta property="og:image" content="Image to be displayed." 
/>
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Finally in your android app you have to share a link to this website, possibly [deep-linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) into your app.

Comment: @johnDoe consider marking this as the answer to help others.

Comment: @johnDoe accepting an answer is a stackoverflow feature.
read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry did not know that as i am new here!! i Hope i did it now