# How to process links like in common chat apps?

Tags: java, android

I want to process links like most of chat apps by adding related pictures or text to the link.

PS: the picture is not necessarly in the link, ex: www.dummydata.png

this image can be helpful:

[image]

Comment: They're just grabbing the linked page and summarizing the first paragraph.  You can do that yourself, but its not built into the OS, so you'll have to write code to figure out what the summary should be.

Comment: is there an open-source library that can help??

Answer (score 0):

It's called The [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)

You basically need to add some *meta* tags to your content.
If you manage the server side, you'll be able to support it. If not, it's not up to you.

See an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478393/10470378)

To retrieve theses tags you can use [this](https://github.com/johndeverall/opengraph-java) library. Just design a view that similar to the one in the picture and populate it.